# What is the 'i1l' hidden form element for in Stack Overflow/Exchange/Super User?

Tags: discussion, design, javascript

I have noticed that a mysterious hidden form element called "i1l" is magically added (with JavaScript, no doubt) to the middle of the form when submitting a new question.

Its value appears to be a Base64 value of something (but isn't actually).

This "i1l" hidden input is not mentioned anywhere in the HTML code. Neither is its value.

My questions:

1. What is it for?
2. How is it added to the form? Is it JavaScript? If so, which one? I searched a very long time.
3. What should its value be set to?

Comment: Appears to be part of the XSRF protection.